# Is there a way to reference your numbered equations?

Tags: cross-referencing

Here is an excerpt document

```
\begin{align}
f(x) &= g(x) + h(x)//
&= 3x + 8x^2 + 1//
&= 3 + 8 + 1//
\end{align}
```

So when I compile this (assuming this is the only thing I Have), LaTeX is going to number the lines 1,2,3.

I want to be able to reference those lines because in the future, I may add more \equations or more \aligns and I may put them before or after. Is there a way to reference the lines without manually typing $(1)$, $(2)$?

Comment: A tip: `amsmath` package and `\tag` command.

Comment: Could you please make your code fully compilable? It helps a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile it twice or more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
E &\not= mc^2 \label{Einstein}\\
PV &= nRT \label{Gas}
\end{align}
\newpage
Please see equation~\ref{Einstein} on page~\pageref{Einstein}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: since `amsmath` is being used, it's better to use `\eqref` rather than just `\ref`. this will put the number in parentheses, and keep the whole thing upright even in an italic environment (e.g. a theorem).  `\pageref` will still work in the usual way.

Comment: It's not working when it is inside mdframed environment

Comment: @sidht: The answerer could not know that you want to have an `mdframed` environment, since you gave no information on that, especially no MWE as Malipivo asked for...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to refer to the three lines in your align environment. First you'll have to provide a label to each line, then you can refer to them using \ref, \eqref, \fref. To make that clear, I posted a whole mwe.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{fancyref}
\newcommand{\bs}{\ensuremath{\backslash}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:first}
f(x) &= g(x) + h(x)\\
\label{eq:second}
&= 3x + 8x^2 + 1\\
\label{eq:third}
&= 3 + 8 + 1
\end{align}

My first equation with label~\ref{eq:first}. My second equation with label~\ref{eq:second}. And my third equation with label~\ref{eq:third}.
\vskip 1em
You can also try \bs eqref. Then you'll get: My first equation with label~\eqref{eq:first}. My second equation with label~\eqref{eq:second}. And my third equation with label~\eqref{eq:third}.
\vskip 1em
Or, you can try \bs fref using the fancyref package which automatically refers to the correct page and gives you the name of the reference object, i.e. 'equation' in this case: My first equation with label~\fref{eq:first}. My second equation with label~\fref{eq:second}. And my third equation with label~\fref{eq:third}. That way you can easily refer to equations, sections, figures, tables on other pages. Try something like this: \fref{eq:nextpage} or \fref{eq:faraway}.
\newpage
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:nextpage}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\newpage
\newpage
\newpage
\newpage
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:faraway}
f(x)=x^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```